# PHP Paypal IPN Method - sandbox test login details

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm working through ssetting up taking Paypal payments for the first time. I'm fairly new to PHP, so I'm using their simplest method, Instant Payment Notifications, where you payment form redirects to Paypal, the user enters their details, and then depending on whether the payment was successful or not, they are redirected back to one of your pages, specified by you in the call to their page. Great!

In the background, a hand-shake process goes on with your "notify" php page, which you also specify, which they call to tell you what has happened so you can perform back-end DB stuff, independant of the pages shown to the user. Great.

My question is, in sandbox mode, when the user is directed to the paypal payment page and needs to login (i.e. me, testing), where can I find credentials to log in with? Because it's the sandbox page, my business/personal account details don't work. I cannot find anything on the (rather confusing) paypal site. How do I log in and simulate a successfuly or denied payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the credentials, which are on paypal Dashboard (here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications). Click on SANDBOX > Accounts. This should show test business and personal accounts. Click on the ellipsis next to the account and then Vew/Edit Account. This will show a popup with the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using their simplest method, Instant Payment Notifications, where you payment form redirects to Paypal, the user enters their details, and then depending on whether the payment was successful or not, they are redirected back to one of your pages, specified by you in the call to their page. Great!

That's not the simplest method, it's the oldest method (20 years old?), and not something you should be integrating in 2021.

Instead, follow the current [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Within the second route, when the capture API response is successful, store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* sending your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair your 2 routes with the JS frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Oh no... yet another method to learn and understand. Thank you for your reply. I'll have a read.

Comment: I'm working through the process you've described above, but it answers a different question to that which I asked. I've found the actual answer out, so I'm going to add that below for completeness.